# Custom value returned by typeof

Tags: javascript, typeof

Is there any way to return a custom type instead of "object"? On the next case, I would want to return i.e. "i16"

```
>function Int16(v) { this.v=v }; var n = new Int16(10);

>typeof n
"object"
>Object.prototype.toString.call(n)
"[object Object]"
```

Comment: `n instanceof Int16` returns true. Don't know if that helps ;)

Comment: If it is not possible, then I could add a method to return the value.

Comment: Other than using `instanceof` I really don't know any other way. Again, operator overloading is not really possible in JS (unfortunately).

Comment: @Yoshi, at the end I'm using `instanceof`, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add a custom "typeof" property to your classes.  Then have a function something like (untested):

```
mytypeof : function (v) {
  type = typeof v;
  return type === "object" && typeof(v["typeof"]) != "undefined" ? v["typeof"] : type;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can’t overload `typeof` — it always returns the base type.

In the given example, you could use the constructor property:

```
function Int16(v) { this.v=v }; 
> var n = new Int16(10);
> n.constructor.name
"Int16"
> n.constructor === Int16
true
```

Comment: While I thought it was somewhat helpful, nothing here returns a custom value from `typeof`.

Comment: Yipes, I don’t like this answer I gave. You’re right, of course — I was answering a different question from the OP’s. I mean, maybe it got him/her to the right place, but still. Many apologies. The actual answer is “no, `typeof` can’t be overloaded. You get System.Type object only, so the base type (or “object”). (To be fair, it looks like the OP wanted type info for an Int16, so my answer is sorta right?)